# Взлом пароля архива брутфорсом

Tags: c#, c++

Примерный пароль - %B-F6y9$Yq9wzbgenqh_NQaH8W-53S?+mskr4T5x$LN-XrcAGd_g8fcpP&C_&!9#^u

К этому нету фиксированной длинны пароля.

Кто знает как:

- как просчитать сколько комбинаций всего вмещает данный пароль?
- какая вычислительная мощность нужна для взлома(процессор или видеокарта)?
- возможно ли увеличить вычислительную мощность?
- как просчитать время полного прохода брутфорса?
- можно ли сделать такую программу с помощью C#(консольное приложение)?

P.S. Я не собираюсь взламывать Пентагон))) Просто стало интересно возможно ли и можно ли передавать важные данные в архиве с таким паролем.

Comment: «сколько комбинаций» — возведите количество символов, которые могут использоваться в пароле, в степень длины пароля. // «мощность» — возьмите столько видеокарт, сколько сможете, измерьте скорость перебора на них и сложите в общую производительность. // «время полного брутфорса» — умножьте число комбинаций на производительность ваших видеокарт. // «можно ли сделать такую программу» — можно, но не нужно, потому что уже есть hashcat

Comment: Нашел вот такие данные по паролям, далее думайте сами, нужно оно вам или нет ) [https://pikabu.ru/story/skolko_vremeni_zaymet_]https://pikabu.ru/story/skolko_vremeni_zaymet_u_khakera_vzlom_parolya_v_2022_godu_8890391()

Comment: @SwaD эта ссылка предполагает использование одного прохода MD5, но в 2022 так никто в здравом уме не делает, поэтому эта информация не имеет никакого практического смысла

Comment: Указать метод шифрования. Существуют разные методы шифрования данных. Для каждого конкретного метода есть свои оценки надёжности пароля. Например обычное хor шифрование на больших текстах позволяет "вскрыть" даже такой сложный пароль. Без метода шифрования это разговор ниочём.

Comment: Как просчитать сколько комбинаций всего вмещает данный пароль = к-во знаков в наборе возвести в степень к-ва знаков, допустим у вас 26*3 грубо т.е. 75. И возвести в степень по колличеству букв. Вот если у вас 50 то выйдет 75 в 50-той, т.е. 5.6*10E93 т.е. 93 степень десятки грубо.

Comment: Как просчитать время полного прохода брутфорса = к*во комбинаций умноженное на среднее время одной проверки. В зависимости от метода - вторая величина может быть от 0,0001 сек до 1000+ секунд.

Comment: Также важен размер сообщения. Если он равен размеру пароля *в битах* и этот пароль применяется только один раз, то такое сообщение невозможно расшифровать в принципе. А если сообщение содержит в себе белый шум, то определить, правильный он или нет - **невозможно**, даже если данных много. Частично ответить можно только если известна информация в сообщении.

Comment: 26 букв * 2 + 10 цифр + 10 спец. символов (`%-$_?+&!#^`) = 72 вариантов символов. Длина пароля в вопросе = 66 символов. Кол-во различных паролей = `72^66`, что примерно равно `3.8 * 10^122`. Для сравнения, 256-битный счётчик может принимать примерно `1.2 * 10^77` состояний. Ни один _классический_ компьютер не может перебрать такой счётчик за разумное время, [даже если он будет питаться от сферы Дайсона вокруг Солнца и расходовать энергию очень эффективно](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1160). В теории шансы перебрать грубой силой хотя бы половину всех паролей оптимизма не внушают.

Comment: P.S. Но мне думается, более детальный анализ покажет, что на практике очередной символ пароля генерируется конструкцией наподобие `return "abcde...."[std::rand() % 72]`, или внезапно выяснится какой-нибудь иной фатальный недостаток. И подбор пароля брутфорсом запросто окажется под силу даже кофемашине.

Comment: @wololo, можно поподробнее объяснить что имелось ввиду в последнем комментарии.

Comment: @JuniorOne что если пароль генерируется по предсказуемому алгоритму, то подобрать даже очень длинный пароль не составит никакого труда